# Why does the Copy Constuctor fail to "copy"

Tags: c++, tree, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I am trying to better understand copy constructors.

When I create a new instance of the private values within the copy constructor,it should be different from the initial value.

However, this is not the case. I am not assigning the values via a reference and neither am I assigning a pointer, yet when I look at the debugger, the memory locations remain unchanged.

What is the 'new' doing if the resulting action remains the same?

```
// copy control within a template
NTree(const NTree& aOtherNTree)
{
    fKey = new T;
    fNodes[N] = new NTree<T, N>;

    fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i];
    }
```

Full Code

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>

#include "TreeVisitor.h"
#include "DynamicQueue.h"

template <class T, int N>
class NTree {
private:
    const T* fKey; // 0 for empty NTree
    NTree<T, N>* fNodes[N]; // N subtress of degree N

    NTree(); // sentinel constructor

public:
    static NTree<T, N> NIL; // sentinel

    NTree(const T& aKey); // a simple NTree with key and N subtrees of degree N

    bool isEmpty() const; // is tree empty
    const T& key() const; // get key (node value)

    // indexer (allow for result modification by client - no const in result)
    NTree& operator[](unsigned int aIndex) const;

    // tree manipulators (using constant references)
    void attachNTree(unsigned int aIndex, const NTree<T, N>& aNTree);
    const NTree& detachNTree(unsigned int aIndex);

    // depth-first traversal
    void traverseDepthFirst(const TreeVisitor<T>& aVisitor) const;

    // copy control
    NTree(const NTree& aOtherNTree)
    {
        fKey = new string;
        fNodes[N] = new NTree<string, N>;

        fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i];
        }
    }

    ~NTree()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                if (!fNodes[i]->isEmpty()) {
                    delete fNodes[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NTree& operator=(const NTree& aOtherNTree)
    {
        fKey = new T;
        fNodes[N] = new NTree<T, N>;

        fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // breadth-first traversal
    void traverseBreadthFirst(const TreeVisitor<T>& aVisitor) const
    {
        DynamicQueue<const NTree<T, N>*> lQueue;
        lQueue.enqueue(this);

        while (!lQueue.isEmpty()) {
            const NTree<T, N>& head = *lQueue.top();
            lQueue.dequeue();

            aVisitor.visit(head.key());

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (head.fNodes[i]->fKey != NULL) {
                    lQueue.enqueue(&head[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// implementation

template <class T, int N>
NTree<T, N> NTree<T, N>::NIL;

// sentinel constructor
template <class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::NTree()
{
    fKey = (T*)0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        fNodes[i] = &NIL;
}

// node constructor
template <class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::NTree(const T& aKey)
{
    fKey = &aKey;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        fNodes[i] = &NIL;
}

// isEmpty
template <class T, int N>
bool NTree<T, N>::isEmpty() const
{
    return this == &NIL;
}

// key
template <class T, int N>
const T& NTree<T, N>::key() const
{
    if (!isEmpty())
        return *fKey;
    else
        throw std::domain_error("Empty NTree.");
}

// indexer
template <class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>& NTree<T, N>::operator[](unsigned int aIndex) const
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw std::domain_error("Empty NTree!");

    if (aIndex < N && fNodes[aIndex] != &NIL) {
        return *fNodes[aIndex]; // return reference to subtree
    }
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Illegal subtree index!");
}

// tree manipulators
template <class T, int N>
void NTree<T, N>::attachNTree(unsigned int aIndex, const NTree<T, N>& aNTree)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw std::domain_error("Empty NTree!");

    if (aIndex < N) {
        if (fNodes[aIndex] != &NIL)
            throw std::domain_error("Non-empty subtree present!");

        fNodes[aIndex] = (NTree<T, N>*)&aNTree;
    }
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Illegal subtree index!");
}

template <class T, int N>
const NTree<T, N>& NTree<T, N>::detachNTree(unsigned int aIndex)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw std::domain_error("Empty NTree!");

    if ((aIndex < N) && fNodes[aIndex] != &NIL) {
        const NTree<T, N>& Result = *fNodes[aIndex]; // obtain reference to subtree
        fNodes[aIndex] = &NIL; // set to NIL
        return Result; // return subtree (reference)
    }
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Illegal subtree index!");
}

template <class T, int N>
void NTree<T, N>::traverseDepthFirst(const TreeVisitor<T>& aVisitor) const
{
    // visit every subtree (no invisit)
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        aVisitor.preVisit(key());
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fNodes[i]->traverseDepthFirst(aVisitor);
        }
        aVisitor.postVisit(key());
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "NTree.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what memory addresses you are referring to, but contrary to your claim *"neither am I assigning a pointer"*, your code does in fact assign a pointer. Many of them, in fact. That's pretty much all it does, is assign pointers. First here:

```
fKey = new T;
```

That's a pointer assignment. So is this:

```
fNodes[N] = new NTree<T, N>;
```

That one also happens to be an assignment to an out of bounds element of an array. That is, `fNodes` is an array of `N` pointers, `fNodes[N-1]` is the last element (pointer) in that array, and `fNodes[N]` is out of bounds.

This is also a pointer assignment:

```
fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;
```

It is also a memory leak, since you've now written over the value that was returned from the call to `new T` earlier in the function. And so have no access to, and no way to deallocate that object.

Then finally, your for loop consists of N pointer assignments.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i];
}
```

You are simply copying the pointers from `aOtherNTree.fNodes` to `fNodes`.

Comment: Usually what you want when making a copy constructor is that you want the values of all members to be the same as the previous object, but at different memory addresses. You don't want two objects to hold a pointer to the same address, because maybe the destructor calls `delete` on that pointer and you delete the memory twice.

Comment: @MivVG That is what I'm trying to do, but as you can see from my code snippet it's not going very well.

Comment: You have to do it like explained [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/915-shallow-vs-deep-copying/). Basically in your case this becomes `*fKey = *other.fKey`

Comment: @MivVG I tried that, and it did not work. I looked at the document you sent and they do this         // allocate memory for our copy
        m_data = new char[m_length];
 
        // do the copy
        for (int i=0; i < m_length; ++i)
            m_data[i] = source.m_data[i];                                                   .How is it any different from what I've done?

Comment: For fNodes, what you did is fine, but you are still copying a pointer when copying fKey